# Remove duplicates numbers in sql cell

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm beginner in SQL. Using Teradata.

I need to remove duplicates numbers in `SQL` cell.

For example:

```
In: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6

Out: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

I have over a million similar cells in a column

Comment: This is going to be hard to swing in a SQL database.  Teradata is much more setup to handle this requirement with your data normalized, with each CSV value in a separate record.  Consider normalizing your data.

Comment: What `TD` version are you on?

Comment: @ravioli 16.20.32.17

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
I am not familiar with teradata sql, but I think this solution may work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CellValue 
FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('tmp_test', 'Your SQL Cell String', ',')
 RETURNS 
(
  Outkey VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET UNICODE
 ,CellValue VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
 ) AS dt
```

After this, you can concatenate rows with a cursor. You can see [here](http://dwgeek.com/teradata-split-delimited-fields-table-records-examples.html/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. No, i'm mean duplicate values in one cell

Comment: Ok, If you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` function to place all comma-separated values in rows a filter them with a simple `SELECT DISTINCT.`

Comment: The question has a <teradata> tag, not <sql-server>.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mish-mash of multiple methods and assumes you have XML Services enabled.  I don't have a `TD` system to test on, so it may or many not work, but hopefully it will give you a starting point:

```sql
WITH cte ( 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id, MyCol AS str -- Give an "id" to each row
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT 
  TRIM(
    TRAILING ',' FROM (
      XMLAGG(src.token || ',' ORDER BY src.token) (VARCHAR(10000))
    )
  )
FROM (
  SELECT d.outkey, d.token
  FROM TABLE (
    STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(cte.id, cte.str, ', ')
    RETURNS (outkey integer, tokennum integer, token varchar(10))
  ) as d
  GROUP BY outkey, token -- Remove duplicate entries
) src
GROUP BY src.outkey -- Build new values
;
```

The idea is to split the comma-delimited value, remove the duplicates and then re-build the delimited string with the new de-duplicated values.  Here are some references:

[Split delimited list](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/~kQmnfAg7lN9QjPK9ICRYA)
[Build delimited list](https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/database/convert-a-column-into-a-comma-separated-list-0)

Answer (score 0):

generally it's not good style to have multiple values in one cell (3NF and friends...) - but you can apply this afterwards with STRTOK or the CSV -Functions
To this result you can apply a simple distinct.

Answer (score -1):

Just, for example, you can try this.

Note: you can split data using `delimiter`

> SQL Query

```
    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6';
    DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ','
    DECLARE @temptable TABLE(Items VARCHAR(255))
    DECLARE @idx INT
    DECLARE @slice VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @idx = 1
        IF LEN(@String)<1 OR @String IS NULL  RETURN

    WHILE @idx!= 0
    BEGIN
        SET @idx = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String)
        IF @idx!=0
            SET @slice = LEFT(@String,@idx - 1)
        ELSE
            SET @slice = @String

        IF(LEN(@slice)>0)
            INSERT INTO @temptable(Items) VALUES(TRIM(@slice))

        SET @String = RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String) - @idx)
        IF LEN(@String) = 0 BREAK       
    END 

    SELECT (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +  Items From @temptable FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''))
```

> OutPut

[image: Output]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm just creating an example.